# jQuery AJAX POST example

Tags: ajax, forms, post

I am trying to post my data and put it into a database, but I can't seem to get it to work... any suggestion would be great!

Thanks!

html file (form) http://pastie.org/private/dkdzrrdvet7jq3muxir8g

js file - http://pastie.org/private/v8knmt6c82t01lqgsopqa

php file - http://pastie.org/private/3ydgbvwbretcku9ivsqhg

Answer (score 0):

you have defined variables "1st", and "2nd" which are not valid JavaScript variable names. so your script fails to parse and execute.

by the way, use

```
var dataString = $("form").eq(0).serialize();
```

to get form field values.

Comment: Brillant got it working  var dataString = $("form").serialize(); used this to serialize and then changed my variables...

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your php code will recognize the data you pass through the javascript ajax's request? You are doing a POST request, not a GET.. i don't know if query string parameters will be added to $_POST

I'd use JSON data..

```
var requestData = {
    first: first, 
    second: second, 
    //...
}
var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(requestData);
```

however, could you be more accurate on the error/errors you get?